# Proving transitivity of Strict Preference

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, economics

Patrick Suppes in his book [Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486406873) on page 63 asks a reader to proof a statement
$$\forall x\forall y\forall z(xPy\land yPz\to xPz)$$ from the theory which he calls "Theory of rational behavior". The statement is based on the notion of weak preference $xQy$, its two properties (lines 1 and 2) and a definition of strict preference $xPy$ (line 3):
$$\begin{array}{p}
\{1\}&(1)&\forall x\forall y\forall z(xQy\land yQz\to xQz)&\text{Transitive property} \\
\{2\}&(2)&\forall x\forall y(xQy \lor yQx)&\text{Axiom of order}\\
\{3\}&(3)&\forall x\forall y(xPy\leftrightarrow \neg yQx)&\text{Definition of strict preferece}\\
\{4\}&(4) & xPy\land yPz & \text{Assumption} \\
\{3,4\}&(5) & \neg yQx\land \neg zQy & \text{from (3)(4) using U.S.} \\
\{2,3,4\}&(6) & xQy & \text{from (2)(5) using U.S.} \\
\{2,3,4\}&(7) & yQz & \text{from (2)(5) using U.S.} \\
\{1,2,3,4\}&(8) & xQz & \text{from (1)(6)(7)} \\
\end{array}
$$
U.S. stands here for the *Rule of Universal Specification*

$xPz$ is equal to $\neg zQx$ by the definition of strict preference on line $3$. So we want to show that $\neg zQx$ logically follows from the premises $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and then use conditioning on line $(4)$ and *The Rule of Universal Generalisation* to prove the given statement. But from $xQz\land(xQz \lor zQx)$ we cannot conclude $\neg zQx$ because according to the *Axiom of order* both $xQz$ and $zQx$ can be *true* together.

I've tried the method of interpretations to check validity of the statement that has to be proven but haven't found any, such that its antecedent would be *true* and conclusion would be *false*.

If my derivation is fine so far, I'm looking for tips which will help me to get to the finish line here. Will appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a proof by contradiction, i.e. continue with:

$$\begin{array}{p}
\{9\}&(9)&\neg xPz&\text{Assumption} \\
\{3,9\}&(2)&zQx&\text{from (3)(9)}\\
\{1,2,3,4,9\}&(10)&zQy&\text{from (1)(6)(10)}\\
\{3,4\}&(11) & \neg zQy & \text{from (5)} \\
\{1,2,3,4,9\}&(12) & \bot & \text{from (10)(11)} \\
\{1,2,3,4\}&(13) & xPz & \text{from (12) using proof by Contradiction} \\
\end{array}
$$

(I wasn't sure how proof by Contradiction works in your system ... but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same conclusion using your approach, namely, that the *axiom of order* wasn't enough to prove $\neg zQx$. However, I found that it could be accomplished by using the *transitive property* along with *modus tollens*. That leads to the following idea: $\neg yQx \to (yQz \to \neg zQx)$. That's a summary of lines 14 through 17:

\begin{array}{l}
& \{1\} & 1. & x\forall y\forall z(xQy\land yQz\to xQz) & \text{ Transitive property }\\
& \{2\} & 2. & \forall x\forall y(xQy \lor yQx) & \text{ Axiom of order }\\
& \{3\} & 3. & \forall x\forall y(xPy\leftrightarrow \neg yQx) & \text{ Definition of strict preference }\\
& \{4\} & 4. & aPb\land bPc & \text{ Assum. }\\
& \{4\} & 5. & aPb & \text{ $\land$E }\\
& \{4\} & 6. & bPc & \text{ $\land$E }\\
& \{3\} & 7. & aPb\leftrightarrow \neg bQa & \text{ 3 UE }\\
& \{3\} & 8. & bPc\leftrightarrow \neg cQb & \text{ 3 UE }\\
& \{3,4\} & 9. & \neg bQa & \text{ 7 $\leftrightarrow$E, 5,7 MP }\\
& \{3,4\} & 10. & \neg cQb & \text{ 8 $\leftrightarrow$E, 6,8 MP }\\
& \{2\} & 11. & bQc \lor cQb & \text{ 2 UE }\\
& \{2\} & 12. & \neg cQb \to bQc & \text{ 11 MI }\\
& \{2,3,4\} & 13. & bQc & \text{ 10,12 MP }\\
& \{1\} & 14. & (bQc \land cQa) \to bQa & \text{ 1 UE }\\
& \{1,3,4\} & 15. & \neg (bQc \land cQa) & \text{ 9,14 MT }\\
& \{1,3,4\} & 16. & \neg bQc \lor \neg cQa & \text{ 15 DM }\\
& \{1,3,4\} & 17. & bQc \to \neg cQa & \text{ 16 MI }\\
& \{1,2,3,4\} & 18. & \neg cQa & \text{ 13,17 MP }\\
& \{3\} & 19. & \neg cQa \to aPc & \text{ 3 UE, $\leftrightarrow$E }\\
& \{1,2,3,4\} & 20. & aPc & \text{ 18,19 MP }\\
& \{1,2,3\} & 21. & (aPb\land bPc) \to aPc & \text{ 4,20 CP }\\
& \{1,2,3\} & 22. & \forall x\forall y\forall z(xPy\land yPz\to xPz) & \text{ 22 UI }\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A small remark: on line 19 there should be an equality sign.

Comment: @anfauglit. I was combining steps. On the right, I listed $\leftrightarrow$E to show that I was eliminating the double arrow along with the universal quantifier.